# Noncommutative analogue of Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal M$ be a noncommutative probability space i.e. there is a trace $\tau$ on $\mathcal M$ such that it is normal, faithful and $\tau(1)=1.$ Let $\tau_1$ be another normal trace on $\mathcal M$. Furthermore, assume that for any $x\geq 0$ in $\mathcal M,$ $\tau(x)=0$ implies $\tau_1(x)=0.$ In this situation what would  be  a  kind of   Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\tau_1$ with respect to $\tau$? (if it exists!)?

Comment: OK, now your revised question is DIFFERENT from your original one, because in the original version you only had semifinite densely-defined traces, whereas now at least one of the traces is finite. Do you also require $\tau_1$ to be a finite trace? or are you still asking  about the semifinite case

Comment: "What would be a kind of Radon-Nikodym derivative?" I don't understand what's being asked.